# Help: Need someone to migrate us from the old wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, installation

When CiviCRM abandoned the WordPress plugin after Version 4.4, and never coded an upgrade path, we got stuck on 4.4 and are now getting the "The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions" message as everything on the shared hosting server has upgraded except CiviCRM.

We are looking for a consultant to migrate our installation to a modern version, either on the new WordPress plugin, or to a subdomain on our shared server space.

Have questions, or want to submit a bid on this job? 
We're a minor political party in one county of Colorado, USA.
You can reach me at (719) 495-6500

Comment: "When CiviCRM abandoned the WordPress plugin after Version 4.4" Not sure what you mean by this - can you provide a bit more detail? (the latest version of CiviCRM works with the latest version of WordPress).

Comment: A proper wordpress plugin will upgrade, either automatically, or with a mouse click.  But CiviCRM abandoned their earlier WordPress users; there is no upgrade button for those of us who installed CiviCRM years ago.

Comment: Ahh, interesting point. But it's definitely not abandoned but you need to follow the instructions at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/